# \captionof messes with paragraph indent

Tags: captions, indentation, paragraphs

```
\documentclass{mwrep}
\usepackage[font=small,compatibility=false]{caption}
\usepackage[chapter]{minted}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
\lipsum[2-3]
\captionof{listing}{Caption of listing}

\lipsum[2-3]
\end{document}
```

In the provided example, using of `\captionof` causes all paragraph indents to disappear (after `\captionof`). How can it be fixed?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

One way is to use `\captionof` inside a group.

```
\documentclass{mwrep}
\usepackage[font=small,compatibility=false]{caption}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
\lipsum[2-3]
\begingroup
\captionof{lstlisting}{Caption of listing}
\endgroup

\lipsum[2-3]
\end{document}
```

Comment: i seem to have said "it's probably best to use \captionof within an enclosing group", in the documentation (i had forgotten that!).  it's not actually easy to make \captionof execute \caption inside a group -- it's actually \caption that causes the problem, and in the normal course of events, \caption is in a float, and hence in a group.

Answer (score 14):

caption warns you:

```
Package caption Warning: \captionsetup{type*=...} or \captionof
(caption)                outside box or environment on input line 13.
See the caption package documentation for explanation.
```

Put a group or environment around the command.