# Caption for align environment

Tags: captions, align

I would like to add a caption under a set of equations that I have in the `align` environment (i.e., `\begin{align}` `...` `\end{align}`). I tried `\caption{...}` inside the `align` environment, but it didn't work.

Comment: Typically a `\caption` is associated with a float, which has an accompanying counter representation. For example `Figure 1:` or `Table 2:`. What would you want in this case for your `align` environment? Or do you not want any of that?

Comment: I would like to get something like `Figure 1:` for my `align` environment.

Comment: Package `caption` or `capt-of` provide a `\captionof{figure}{...}`.

Answer (score 7):

You can force a caption outside a regular float using the [`caption` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) or the tiny [`capt-of` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/capt-of), each providing `\captionof{<float>}` which tricks LaTeX into setting a float-like caption:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,capt-of,lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum*[1]
\begin{align}
  f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
       &= g(x)
\end{align}

\begingroup\vspace*{-\baselineskip}
\captionof{figure}{A beautiful equation.}
\vspace*{\baselineskip}\endgroup

\lipsum*[2]
\end{document}
```

---

For a custom caption, I'd suggest creating a macro to reference the set using something like the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,lipsum}
\newcounter{equationset}
\newcommand{\equationset}[1]{% \equationset{<caption>}
  \refstepcounter{equationset}% Step counter
  \noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{Equation set~\theequationset: #1}}% Print caption
\begin{document}
\lipsum*[1]
\begin{align}
  f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
       &= g(x)
\end{align}
\equationset{A beautiful equation.}

\medskip

\lipsum*[2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. How can I have a customized caption for my `align` environment. E.g., `Equation set 1:` instead of `Figure 1:`.

Comment: The use of `\captionof` without a proper container (such as `center`, `minipage` or similar) can produce unexpected results; I can't find now the question in this site illustrating this in a spectacular way (the problem appeared several pages after `\captionof` had been used without container!).

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: I know that `\captionof` *without* container allows you to use `\caption` as-is afterwards, since `\@captype` has been set - the only test used to see whether `\caption` is valid.

Comment: @Javad: Do you have a bunch of these "equation sets"? I've added something to manage this. Perhaps it's sufficient.

Comment: @Werner but that's not what I meant; using no container can produce odd results (not errors, but certainly problems). I wish I could find the relevant thread :(

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Were you thinking of any of these? [\captionof messes with paragraph indent](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/62875) [parskip=half option ignored after captionof](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/224348)

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: `\captionof` sets `\@captype`. It means that you can use `\captionof{table}{..}` in one place, and then somewhere else `\caption` (outside of a float, but in the same group) and still yield a `table` caption.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Those can be used as examples too, but no. The one I have in mind is more "spectacular". The problem manifested after several pages.

Comment: @Werner I know, you said that already, Gonzalo was looking for something else.

Comment: @Werner - I used this method and got nice captions. Then I added corresponding `\label{}`'s.  But where my caption might be `Table 2.`, a reference to the label comes out as `2.6`.  How can I fix that?

Comment: @CAB: Are you using `\equationset{Caption\label{abc}}`?

Comment: @Werner, no, I had the `\label` on a separate line.  It works fine now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A little tweak on Werner's answer. His answer has the problem of not allowing **line break inside the caption**.
[image]

I have fixed the problem modifying his code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{ifthen}

%-- Defines a CAPTION for a set of equations and numbers
%   the set of equations is numbered
% note: the caption adapts the text alignment to the length. 
\newcounter{captionedequationset} %numbering
\newdimen\captionlength
\newcommand{\captionedequationset}[1]{
    \refstepcounter{captionedequationset}% Step counter
    \setlength{\captionlength}{\widthof{#1}} %
    \addtolength{\captionlength}{\widthof{Equation set~\thecaptionedequationset: }}
    %If the caption is shorter than the line width then
    % the caption is centred, otherwise is flushed left.
    \ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\captionlength < \linewidth }} %
    {\begin{center}
            Equation set~\thecaptionedequationset: #1
        \end{center}} 
    { \begin{flushleft} 
        Equation set~\thecaptionedequationset: #1 %
        \end{flushleft}}}

\begin{document}

  \begin{gather}
      ax^2 +bx+c \\
      \sin(\omega x) + \cos(\omega x) 
  \end{gather}
  \captionedequationset{Lovely!} 

  \begin{gather}
      ax^2 +bx+c \\
      \sin(\omega x) + \cos(\omega x) 
  \end{gather}
  \captionedequationset{These are probably the cutest equations ever seen in \LaTeX---I really like them!---but somebody else may think differently. }

\end{document}
```

Enjoy your equations+captions. :)
[image]