# parskip=half option ignored after captionof

Tags: captions, koma-script, paragraphs

Using `minted`, I'm typesetting listings that are longer than one page. However, using the `listing` environment that comes with `minted` does not work, because it does not break at the and of a page. I have found a possible solution by using `captionof` so it still appears in the list of listings.

However, after using it, the parskip is reset and the option `half` is not used anymore, for any text below it.

```
\documentclass[
    12pt,
    paper=a4,
    parskip=half ]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage{libertine} 
\usepackage[libertine,cmintegrals,cmbraces,vvarbb]{newtxmath} 
\usepackage{inconsolata} 
\usepackage{minted} 
\usepackage{caption} 
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum
    \begin{minted}{python}
        def foo():
            # Here would be code longer than one page
            return 0
    \end{minted}
    \captionof{listing}{Some Text}
    \lipsum 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get a warning:

```
Package caption Warning: \captionsetup{type*=...} or \captionof
(caption)                outside box or environment on input line 24.
See the caption package documentation for explanation.
```

This is the cause of problem you are facing. As a remedy to this put `minted` inside a group

```
\bgroup
    \begin{minted}{python}
        def foo():
            # Here would be code longer than one page
            return 0
    \end{minted}
    \captionof{listing}{Some Text}
\egroup
```

Your code:

```
\documentclass[
    12pt,
    paper=a4,
    parskip=half ]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[libertine,cmintegrals,cmbraces,vvarbb]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{inconsolata}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum
    \bgroup
    \begin{minted}{python}
        def foo():
            # Here would be code longer than one page
            return 0
    \end{minted}
    \captionof{listing}{Some Text}
    \egroup
    \lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

As an aside KOMA defines a similar command

```
\captionof{float type}[entry]{title}
```

and you don't need to load `caption` package.

Comment: I would extend the solution with the KOMA command.

Comment: @Manuel It is just removing `\usepackage{caption}` from the code.

Comment: I have added the caption package to get the labels in bold.

Comment: @ap0 OK. That was meant just for your information.

Comment: @HarishKumar Yeah, but I meant that it's more likely that people start using KOMA's `\captionof` if you put it in a full answer instead of just commenting about it.

Comment: @ap0 `\addtokomafont{captionlabel}{\bfseries}`?

Comment: @ap0 That too is possible with KOMA itself. See Manuel's comments. Bottom line is: whenever KOMA offers something it is better to use them.

Comment: @Manuel, thank you. But I do not quite understand why your solutions should be prefered to `\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}`.

Comment: @ap0 Because some times they may clash. :-)

Comment: @ap0 Because the author of KOMA-script takes high care of his own classes and packages. A more generic package like `caption` doesn't know all the features by KOMA and might break stuff. It's like understanding relativity, the special approach is the simplest, the more generic solution is a lot harder to get.

Comment: Additional remark: if you have an element that spans over multiple pages, place the caption __above__ the element. Also consider this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3243/why-should-a-table-caption-be-placed-above-the-table as code is text-like and not image-like.