# Caption for a model in the align environment

Tags: align, captions, counters

I'd like to caption my model with "model 4.1: A beautiful equation".

I could manage to write "model 1: A beautiful equation" with the following code i found in the forum [Caption for align environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172452/caption-for-align-environment):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,lipsum}
\newcounter{equationset}
\newcommand{\equationset}[]{% \equationset{<caption>}
    \refstepcounter{equationset}% Step counter
    \noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{model~\theequationset: #1}}% Print caption
\begin{document}
    \begin{align}
        f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
        &= g(x)
    \end{align}
    \equationset{A beautiful equation.}
    
    \medskip
\end{document}
```

My supervisor is very strict, which is why it has to be called 4.1. The code is copied and I don't understand it enough, so I don't know how to adapt it. I haven't even figured out how to at least change it to "model 4:". Does anyone know a solution? (Can also be something completely different, the main thing is that it works).

Comment: Is the 4 by any chance a section number? If so, you could do `\numberwithin{equationset}{section}`.

Comment: probably a stupid question - but where do i put that?

Comment: It should be in your preamble meaning anywhere between `\documentclass` and `\begin{document}` but after `\usepackage{amsmath}`

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to get familiar with `float`, a package for custom floats, define your own float as `model`, define a label for it, e.g. `Model` and get access to a list of your folats

See the example

[image]

The following redefines equation numbers to include sections

```
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
```

which I haven't included in the code but should be placed in your preamble.

```latex
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{amsmath,lipsum}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

% \pretocmd{\@startsection}{\protect\setcounter{modelc}{0}}{}{}
\newcounter{modelc}
\numberwithin{equation}{chapter}
\numberwithin{modelc}{chapter}
\crefname{modelc}{model}{models}
\Crefname{modelc}{Model}{Models}
% \crefformat{modelc}{model~#2(#1)#3}   % Custom formatting -> model (C.M)
% \Crefformat{modelc}{Model~#2(#1)#3}   %                   -> Model (C.M)


\NewDocumentEnvironment{model}{O{} m +b}{%
    % #1 - label (optional)
    % #2 - caption
    \refstepcounter{modelc} \notblank{#1}{\label{#1}}{}
    
    #3
    %%% Increase a counter and set the label if provided
    %%% Formatting a caption
    \settowidth{\dimen0}{Model \themodelc}%
    \settowidth{\dimen1}{#2}%
    \ifdim \dimen1 > \dimexpr(\textwidth - \dimen0 - 1em)
        \dimen1=\dimexpr(\textwidth - \dimen0 - 1em)\fi
    \begingroup
        \centering
        \parbox[t]{\dimexpr(\dimen0 + 1em)}{Model \themodelc: }%
        \parbox[t]{\dimexpr(\dimen1)}{#2}%
        \vspace{\baselineskip}
        \par
    \endgroup
}{}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\chapter{The first chapter}
\lipsum[1][1-2]

\section{This is a section}
\lipsum[1][1]


\chapter{The second chapter} \label{chap:second}
\section{This is a section with a model}
\lipsum[1][2]
\begin{model}[mod:beq]{A very very long description of a extremely beautiful equation spanning multiple lines}
    \begin{align}                 % Only caption
        f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \label{eq:eq1} \\
        &= g(x)               \label{eq:eq2} 
    \end{align}
\end{model}

\lipsum[1][3-5]


\chapter{The final chapter}
\lipsum[1][3-5]

\chapter{This is a star variant section}
\lipsum[1][6]

\section{This is a section with another model}
\lipsum[1][5]
\begin{model}{A beautiful equation}    % Caption + label
    \begin{align}
        f(\mathbf{x}) &= x_1 - x_2
    \end{align}
\end{model}

Reference to \Cref{mod:beq} on \cpageref{mod:beq} in \cref{chap:second}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works well. But now I get a bar with the heading instead of just a normal label at the bottom. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @CélineMeister I don't get any bar anywhere. The screenshot is what the result is. Have you compiled my example in a separate file or have you copied it to existing code and then tried to compile everything together?

Comment: I tried to compile everything together.. it works separately. No idea, where i made the mistake, looks right to me! But never mind, i'll just leave it like that... at least the numeration is correct :-) Thank you!

Comment: It's hardly possible to get the idea without the full code. Are you getting any error? Sometimes the order of loaded packages matters so you could try to move `\usepackage{float}` upwards, even right after `\documentclass..` and see if that helps.

Comment: @CélineMeister I edited the answer. There's a variant of the solution with a custom environment. Because it's not based on floats, you cannot have a list of models.

Comment: yes i get that, but it's a huge document and i have no idea where the mistake is :-). 
Thank you so much for your effort! I'm going to try the edited answer right away!

Comment: works perfectly! thank you so much!

Comment: one last question... it now displays "4.2.1" since it's under section 4.2. Is it possible that it still starts on 4.1? Should have mentioned this earlier, i'm sorry.

Comment: @Céline In lines starting from `\numberwithin`, change `section` to `chapter`.

Comment: perfect, thank you :-)