# Unexpected cancellation of indent happened when combining using caption and capt-of package

Tags: captions, indentation, incompatibility

The paragraphs after "captionof" do not indent properly. Either comment out `\usepackage{caption}` or `\captionof{figure}{figure}` take the indentations back.

But I need the capt-of package and also caption package to redefine "labelsep" to be space other than colon. Is there an alternative way to do so.

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
before caption before caption before caption before caption before caption before caption before caption before caption before caption before caption before caption before caption before caption before caption before caption before caption before caption before caption before caption before caption before caption before caption 

\captionof{figure}{figure}

after caption after caption after caption after caption after caption after caption after caption after caption after caption after caption after caption after caption after caption after caption after caption after caption after caption after caption after caption after caption after caption after caption after caption after caption 

after caption after caption after caption after caption after caption after caption after caption after caption after caption after caption after caption after caption after caption after caption after caption after caption after caption after caption after caption after caption after caption after caption after caption after caption 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question already has an answer here: [\captionof messes with paragraph indent](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62875/captionof-messes-with-paragraph-indent) but I'd like to add a bit of explanation.

The [documentation](http://ctan.megagod.net/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/caption/caption-eng.pdf) of `\captionof` in `caption` package (page 18) says that " ... so you should use both
`\captionof` and `\captionof*` only inside boxes or environments."  So putting the command in a group of itself like `{\captionof{figure}{figure}}` should be a legit way.

Also you do not need to `\usepackage{capt-of}` as `caption` package also provides `\captionof`.